# How to undo this?

Tags: unix, terminal

I set up a soft link on my MAMP system like this

```
ln -s php5.3 php5
```

but I think it might have been the cause of system problems that just appeared

does anyone know how to undo it?

Answer (score 2):

```
rm php5
```

The symbolic link is a file and can be removed by `rm` like regular files. This won't affect the target.

Answer (score 2):

Use `unlink` instead of `rm`, it's much safer.

```
unlink php5
```

Answer (score 1):

**Delete** the symbolic link like this:

```
rm -i php5
```